# Voronoi Texture Node with differing options

Tags: texturing, displacement

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJGphR_LBoM 
When he adds a Voronoi Texture as displacement, his Voronoi Node looks like this:

[image]

but mine looks like this

[image]

I've double checked it a dozen times, and I am now quite sure that it got updated or changed, so how can I correctly pattern to Crackle?

Comment: @JtheNinja covered it. The tutorial is using 2.80, you're using 2.81+, and the node has been improved. If you're interested in how it's done, [this](https://thebookofshaders.com/12/) is a nice reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voronoi textures work by scattering points and connecting their edges to form a kind of mesh, then generating patterns based on distances within that mesh. The crackle pattern is created by measuring how close a shading point is from one of the edges. This results is a pattern of cracks following the random layout of the "edges" of the point mesh.

So to get the crackle pattern, you should first set the node to "distance to edge"
[image: node graph showing the voronoi node in "distance to edge" mode]

If you need an actual hard-edged crack pattern rather than just the distance to the edge, you can use the math node set to "greater than" to find areas that are more than a specified distance from an edge:

[image: voronoi node with math node added to clip the crack pattern to black and white]

Finally, since this example uses a plane with UVs, you can change the texture from 3D to 2D. This will prevent the pattern from getting thicker where it intersects corners of the pattern in 3D space.

[image: voronoi node changed to 2D, fixing varying thickness of the crackle lines]

Comment: so no displacement? Sorry im fairly new to this

Comment: This example just shows how to generate the crackle pattern with the voronoi node in 2.81+. You can plug it into displacement or wherever else you wish.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I ran into the same problem but after playing around, figured it out.

Instead of connecting Color - Vector, connect Distance to Vector.