# How to reproduce "Crackle" Voronoi option in Blender 3.6?

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

I want to create similar Voronoi texture in Blender 3.6.

[image: Voronoi texture example]

Comment: So that's the problem? Nodes are basically the same in 2.8 and 3.6

Comment: @Crantisz Voronoi texture node is different in 3.6. It is missing Crackle option. Anyway I am not able to reproduce this effect using workflow from the video. The closest I get is by subtracting two Voronoi texture nodes.

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162867/voronoi-texture-node-with-differing-options#162869

Comment: No. Unfortunately it doesn't reproduce the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want.

Buried somewhere in the comments below that tutorial video, Shadowreaper8435 said that he originally did the tutorial in Blender 2.8. When he opened it in 2.81, Blender automatically changed the nodes to the setup using the subtract node with two Voronoi texture nodes.

Duplicating his effort, this is what I get when I open a file created in 2.80, in 3.6.2:
[image]

The image in your question appears to be at a point before he adjusts the Color Ramp node that connects to the Mix Shader, so that is what this image represents.

This is the node tree that 3.6.2 creates from the 2.80 saved file. It is as I used it to for the above image:
[image]

Here is the 2.80 .blend file: [image]

Comment: Yes. This looks like the same effect. Thanks.